# How to preserve a “target” attribute on links in overlays?

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

How can I preserve `target` attribute functionality in Drupal 7 overlays? They appear to always be overwritten with `target="_parent"`.

I have added a link to the help text of a field. I would like to open the link in a new browser tab/window so that the user’s input in the form is not lost when following the link. However, the `target` attribute appears to be overwritten and the link opens in the same overlay.

Here’s the relevant portion of the help text:

```html
 I agree to the site’s <a href="../../node/5" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, all links can be excluded from being processed by the Overlay module. Just add a CSS class named `overlay-exclude` to the `class` attribute of the link.

That has also solved my `target` attribute issue:

```html
 I agree to the site’s <a class="overlay-exclude" href="../../node/5" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>.
```